# R Markdown doesn't show GoogleVis charts

Tags: r, r-markdown, googlevis

I am trying to use a couple of GoogleVis chars in the R markdown file for illustration. However, the result R markdown file doesn't show any of the GoogleVis charts and it doesn't yield any errors or warnings. Here is the link on the Rpub to the R markdown:

https://rpubs.com/VoyagerWSH/688334

I have enabled Adobe Flash in my browser and I have used the following r chunk settings.

```
echo=TRUE, results='asis'
```

And I have also included the following using in the markdown header:

```
output:
   html_document:
    self_contained: no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following statement in the R chunks to write only the chart component of the HTML file into the output file

```
op <- options(gvis.plot.tag='chart')
```